# PHP GET id from articles.php

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have an Articles.php page and a Single.php page. Articles.php runs a foreach loop listing all of the articles. The href anchor for each article is:

```
<a href="single.php?id=<?php echo $article['id'];
```

When the article link is click the URL becomes:

```
example.com/single.php?id=*ID*
```

I am having trouble grabbing that article ID on the single page to show the MySQL row specific to that id. The following was suggested:

```
$id = filter_var($_GET['id'] ?? false, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
if($id !== false){
    //show the article, i.e. select * from .... where id = id ...
    echo "WORKING";
}else{
    //show the error like 404
    echo "ERROR";
}
```

Should this be:

```
$id = $_GET($article['id'])
```

I am having trouble making this work.

Comment: Hi how about you check if the id is set before you try to get it. if( isset($_GET['id']) ){  $id = $_GET['id']; } something like that

Comment: Jut do an `echo $_GET['id'];` to make sure you're getting the id you expect. You're also using `filter_var()` incorrectly as there is no `??` or `false` allowed there.

Comment: I was overthinking this, it's working now. Thank you very much everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Send value to another page using..

```
<a href="single.php?id=<?php echo $article['id'];?>">Link</a> //missing php close tag here
```

Then get it using

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: it could have easily been a suggestion or comment. Not comprehensive an answer ...

Comment: @Mueyiwa Moses Ikomi this is final answer of question.Mistake done by fresher in php.

Answer (score 1):

```
ok lets try this.
on page 1 => article.php
# we assume
database query here

$query = mysqli_query(//query here);
// we then use a while loop

while($q = $query->fetch_array())
{

  echo '<a href="single.php?id='.$q['id'].'">'.$q['article_name'].'</a>'; 

}


ok on page single.php

# we now have example.com/single.php?id=1 eg.

// there are many ways to grab the id

# option 1

 // inside single.php

 // method 1

  $article_id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : "";

// method 2

  $article_id2 = "";

  if(isset($_GET['id']))
  {
    $article_id2 = $_GET['id'];
  }


 // now you have the value from the GET method within your local variable scope 
 // so choose any of the method above
 // both works

  hope this helps?
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Hek mat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7247090/hek-mat) said you missed the Clossing tags:

```
<a href="single.php?id=<?php echo $article['id'];?>">Link</a>
```

But you your code is also not correct $_GET['id'] is giving always a `string "1"` not a `int 1` and if the id is not set this would cause an error.
So try this:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && intval($_GET['id']) > 0){
    $id = intval($_GET['id']); // now work with $id its an int now 
    //show the article, i.e. select * from .... where id = id ...
    echo "WORKING";
}else{
    //show the error like 404
    echo "ERROR";
}
```